# after clicking anchor jquery validate not working ( Spring MVC + JQuery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

We are developing a project using spring + hibe and jquery which do some form validation and text changing stuff. spring + hibe is working fine. but jquery doesnt. Here goes the scenario:

login.jsp

```
<form:form action="/login" method="post" id="registerForm" modelAttribute="formbean" data-ajax="false">
...
//some input fields
...
<a href="/reg?appId=123456&page=&....">register</a>
...
//some buttons
...
</form:form>
```

register.jsp

```
<form:form action="/reg" method="post" id="registerForm" modelAttribute="formbean" data-ajax="false">
...
//some input fields and buttons
...
</form:form>
```

in the login page ive got an anchor which will go to the register page. 
if i call the two pages using spring mapping pattern /login... or /reg... seperately the jquery validation works pretty well.(validate if the fields are empty or invalid input and so on...). 
BUT if i go to the register page by means of clicking the anchor, the validation will not be executed in the register.jsp. And basicly it submits the form to the server.

I suppose it has something to do with the jquery or ajax. Spring on the otherside should be no problem.

Could someone please tell why the jquery validate plugin doesnt work after the anchor being clicked and help me find the solution. I would really appreciate it.

btw the file i used included for both jsp pages are:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you choose between jquery validation or spring form validation ,combination of them is not good point! however spring tag will execute validation before jquery .
you can use simple

```
        @RequestParam ("param1") String param1
```

In controller instead of use modelAttribute and command,and use plain html form and rely on jquery validation.

Comment: thanks for replying Ali. The jquery only does the basic validation and the spring will validate the business logic. And im not allowed to remove all the jquery validations. :(